# Why is this conversion happening?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
  int a, b;
public:

  test() {
    a=4; b=5;
  }

  test(int i,int j=0) {
    a=i; b=j;
  }

  test operator +(test c) {
     test temp;
     temp.a=a+c.a;
     temp.b=b+c.b;
     return temp;
  }

  void print() {
    cout << a << b;
  }
};

int main() {
  test t1, t2(2,3), t3;
  t3 = t1+2;
  t3.print();
  return 0;
}
```

How can the compiler accept a statement like `t3=t1+2;` where `2` is not an object?

Comment: I see your confusion, but technically, `int`s are objects too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler sees you are invoking `operator+(test)` and attempts to implicitly convert the `2` to a `test` successfully using your `test(int i,int j=0)` constructor.

If you want to make the conversion explicit, you must change the constructor to `explicit test(int i, int j=0)`. In this case, your code would generate a compiler error because `2` cannot be implicitly converted to `test`. You would need to change the expression to `t1 + test(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `test(int i,int j=0)` is a constructor that takes one or two arguments, so a `test` object is created from `2`. In the next stage `test operator +(test c)` is called.

Answer (score 2):

There is a binary `operator+` available which takes two operands of type `test`. Moreover, `test` is implicitly constructible from `int` via the constructor `test(int, int = 0)`. Putting the two together, `t1 + 2` becomes `t1 + test(2, 0)`.

To disallow this silent conversion (which sometimes can cause *very* surprising conversion chains), declare your constructors that accept one single argument as explicit: `explicit test(int, int = 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `test(int i, int j = 0)` is not marked explicit.

Therefore `t1 + 2` is interpreted as `t1.operator+(2)` which is itself interpreted as `t1.operator+(test(2))` (implicit conversion).

If you mark the constructor as `explicit`, an error will occur (during the compilation), saying that `2` cannot be converted into a `test` or that the `operator+` does not match.

Answer (score 0):

In short, because C++ includes *operator overloading*, the ability to define custom implementations of operators for user-defined types. The `operator+()` function shown above is how you define the `+` operator for the type `test`. When the compiler sees an expression in which `+` is applied to a `test` object, it looks for an `operator+` defined in `test` (or a two-argument form defined as a global function with a first argument of type `test` or `test&`.) It then invokes the function, possibly after converting the other argument.

Answer (score 0):

Because your constructor `test(int i,int j=0)` introduces a user defined conversion from `int` to `test`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler creates an object of type Test using its constructor.

```
 t3 = t1 + test(2);
```